# Regex catch pattern over multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble catching a repeating pattern over multiple lines.
I beleive this is an easy task, but I just can't seem to get it to work!

[Check this example](https://regex101.com/r/RTvNnu/1) : `Users of (.*\s*)`

```
Users of 85838NAVSIM_F:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 2 licenses in use)

----- ends here!

  "85838NAVSIM_F" v1.000, vendor: adskflex
  floating license

    1 RESERVATION for PROJECT 1 (SRV02/27000)

----- should catch to here (and repeat on next)!

Users of 67600NAVMAN_F:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 2 licenses in use)

  "67600NAVMAN_F" v1.000, vendor: adskflex
  floating license

    1 RESERVATION for PROJECT 2 (SRV02/27000)
```

Why isn't just `.*` (any character, including new line? multiple times) enough to catch multiple lines? How can I adjust the regex to make it work as intended?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the rule here? How do you define the pattern?

Comment: I want to catch "Users of" and forward until next occurance.

Comment: Ok, like https://regex101.com/r/SXeVCr/1?

Comment: *"Why isn't just `.*` (any character, including new line? multiple times) enough to catch multiple lines?"* Because `.` doesn't match newlines in JavaScript's dialect of regex. To do that, one option is to use an alternation: `.|\n`. But there may be more to your problem than that. Wiktor's here, he'll probably have it covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a tempered greedy token and rely on either `[^]` or `[\s\S]` to match any character since in JS regex, a dot behavior cannot be redefined due to the absence of the DOTALL / `s` modifier.

Use

```
/^Users of (?:(?!^Users of )[\s\S])*/gim
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SXeVCr/4)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the line (as `m` modifier is used, `^` matches the start of string and of a line)
- `Users of`   - a literal char sequence
- `(?:(?!^Users of )[\s\S])*` - a tempered greedy token matching any char (see `[\s\S]` = `[^]`) zero or more times (see `*`) that does not start a `Users of` substring at the start of a line

The same unrolled regex will look like

```
/^Users of .*(?:\r?\n(?!Users of ).*)*/gim
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SXeVCr/3).

Here, the tempered greedy token is unrolled as

- `.*` - the rest of the line after `Users of`
- `(?:\r?\n(?!Users of ).*)*` - zero or more occurrences of:

  - `\r?\n` - a line break  (can be replaced with `(?:\r\n?|\n)` to match any common style line break)...
  - `(?!Users of )` - that is not followed with `Users of` substring
  - `.*`  - the rest of the line.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot! Bit more complicated than I though! =P

Comment: Note that unrolled regex must be more efficient since it will only "stumble" at line breaks. The tempered greedy token will be "stumbling" at each character.